# How to create an Array with AngularJS's ng-model and how to submit using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I have to submit array of values using jquery and angularjs. When i click submit button i'm getting only first array value. How to get all array value using ng-model.Here is my all code https://jsfiddle.net/rijo/6dLxhr7j/ 
Script code given below

```
$scope.onSubmit = function(){
    sum = $scope.obj;
    console.log(sum);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'admin_controller.php',
            data: $.param(sum),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log("OK");
        });
    }
```

Please any one can help.. Thanks!

Comment: The AngularJS framework normally posts data as `'Content-Type: application/json` and there is no need to serialize it with the jQuery param method.

Comment: Look at [StackOverflow: Receive JSON POST with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php).

Answer (score -1):

You have to post data as an object, pass your array as an object attribute value. In this case I'm using the `$http.post` shortcut method.

```
function buildParam(){
    // write any needed logic to get, build your array
    // maybe a loop extracting values from collection, etc.
    var myArray = []; // here your array of values, objects, etc.
    return myArray;
}

$scope.onSubmit = function(){
    sum = {
        myAttr: buildParam()
    };

    $http.post('admin_controller.php', sum).then(
        function(response) {
            console.log('ok');
        }       
    );
}
```

Comment: I want to get the value as dynamic, not a static

Comment: can u give me how to get dynamic values from my html code

Comment: The $http service automatically transforms request data with `angular.toJson`. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Default Transformations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations) or see it for yourself in the [$http service source code line #293](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L293).